# How to force UI test project to "run" MVC project before executing tests?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

I have an MVC project and a UI Test project in my solution.  I added a reference to the MVC project in my UI Test project.  I then added a `TestMethod` that runs and simply navigates to `localhost:8238`, where my MVC project is running locally.  However when I run my tests, `localhost:8238` is inaccessible because the MVC project isn't actually running.  How can my projects be configured to allow for testing an MVC project locally from a different project in the same solution?